# Specifying bullet type when using itemize

Tags: symbols, lists, itemize

Is there a way to get a specific type of bullet instead of the filled bullets when you first activate the itemize command in LaTeX? I am trying to get hollow bullets from the start instead of using nested commands to attempt to create them somehow. Thank you.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package might be useful, combined with some package listed in the [Comprehensive Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{212}]
\item First
\item Second
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dingbat items]

Answer (score 44):

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\circ$}
...
```

where `i`, `ii`, `iii`, etc. refer to the current bullet level.

Comment: Warning: don't work with french option in Babel: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123668/how-can-i-define-bullet-style-for-itemize-with-french-option-babel

Comment: @GabrielSoranzo apparently it does now, at least on my system (Debian 12.2).

Answer (score 23):

One possible way to accomplish it is...

First, include `amssymb` package by adding the line `\usepackage{amssymb}` in the preamble of your document.

```
\begin{itemize}

\item[$\checkmark$] This will give a checkmark bullet.

\item[$\square$] This will give a hollow square bullet.

\item[$\blacksquare$] This will give a filled square bullet.

\item[$\bigstar$] This will give you a bigstar bullet.

\end{itemize}
```

The list of all *keywords* like *square*, *checkmark* etc. can be found in `amssymb` package documentation. Visit: http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/amssymb-symbols.pdf

Answer (score 19):

Try the list environment:

```
\begin{list}{$\circ$}{}  
\item A  
\item B  
\end{list}
```

Comment: What are some other symbols instead of `$\circ$` ?

Comment: @Rajan --- See the comprehensive list  [http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

In LaTeX

```
\item[$\diamond$]
  (your text)
```

will change that item's bullet to a diamond. This works on a per item basis.