# What are original itemize bullet definitions?

Tags: symbols, lists, itemize

We are given a document with original bullet definitions overwritten:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\circ$}
...
```

([Example taken from Richard Durr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19894/7128))

Assume, we want to make list (in such document) with original bullets (using `\begin{itemize}[label=...]`).

What are default definitions of `\labelitemi`, `\labelitemii`, `\labelitemiii`, `\labelitemiv`...?

How to retrieve this information?

Comment: Check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360675/bullets-points-styles/360681

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you do not know where to look for the definitions you can use [`texdef`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texdef). To use it with LaTeX definitions you have to either call it with the option `-t latex` or use the corresponding alias `latexdef` (if the alias is defined on your system).

To check the definition for `\labelitemi` you can issue `texdef -t latex \labelitemi`. To also check where the definition is to be found add the option `-f`. So, to check the definitions for `\labelitemi`, `\labelitemii`, `\labelitemiii` and `\labelitemiv` you can issue

```
texdef -t latex -f \labelitemi \labelitemii \labelitemiii \labelitemiv
```

and on my system it returns:

```
\labelitemi first defined in "article.cls".

\labelitemi:
\long macro:->\textbullet 

\labelitemii first defined in "article.cls".

\labelitemii:
\long macro:->\normalfont \bfseries \textendash 

\labelitemiii first defined in "article.cls".

\labelitemiii:
\long macro:->\textasteriskcentered 

\labelitemiv first defined in "article.cls".

\labelitemiv:
\long macro:->\textperiodcentered
```

If you want to see the available options for `texdef` or learn more about it you can access its documentation with `texdoc texdef`.

Comment: Now a SE answers directs me to a command line again. I.e. this tip is very helpful for later, but it does not answer the actual question. Only @Chel did so.

Answer (score 17):

The original definition is in the class file, e.g. [`article.cls`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

```
\newcommand\labelitemi{\textbullet}
\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}
\newcommand\labelitemiii{\textasteriskcentered}
\newcommand\labelitemiv{\textperiodcentered}
```

If a definition isn't there it's generally in [source2e](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf).

Answer (score 13):

Use `\show` to display the definition of a macro in the terminal, and in the log file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\show\labelitemi
```

Alternatively, to get the output in the pdf or dvi, use `\meaning`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\meaning\labelitemi}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Won't you please add  `\meaning` as it is sometimes easier to read, just for completeness?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides --- What is the best way to use `\meaning`?

Comment: I normally use  `\meaning\labelitemi` with `tt` font.