# Bullets points styles

Tags: beamer, lists, presentations

I am a new user of Latex can anyone suggest me how can I change different styles of bullet points that can be used in a presentation.Now I am using this type of notation for bullet points, how can I change them.Kindly suggest me.[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have the following settings, for example, for each of them you can specify the option between the two brackets.

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[<choice>]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[<choice>]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[<choice>]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[<choice>]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}[<choice>]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}[<choice>]
```

You can choose from these options: `[default], [triangle], [circle], [square], and [ball]`. Besides, you can set your own styles using normal LaTeX code. For example, you may set `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{$\int$}` to have the first level of itemize labeled with the integral sign.

Time now for an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{>>}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[ball]

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}    
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item
  \item two
  \item three
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Item
    \item two
    \item three 
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item
      \item two
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]